# About Confidence interval

Tags: statistics

I don't know how to calculate this questions
PLEASE describe the details of the solutions 
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say it is normally distributed. $65$ is two standard deviations from the mean; so you need the percentage of batteries between $-\infty$ and $\mu-2\sigma$. Normalizing the batteries with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, you need to calculate $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{-2}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx.$$

Comment: why is the μ=0 and what the formula exactly is?                   Now we know the mean=75 σ=5  .                                                                           Can you write your formula on paper or make it clearly so i can take the number in to the formula to calculate.                                      thank you

Comment: The mean is not $0$ *a priori*; it is $75$. I did [this process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution) of transforming a general normal distribution (here, with $\mu=75$ and $\sigma=5$) to the standard normal distribution (with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$) to then calculate the desired probability.